# Getting information from json and using it in a function

Tags: python, json

I'm a beginner for Python. The thing I'm having trouble is selecting the url from my array after searching for the song and using that url to be played in the webbrowser.open_new_tab(). The py file is:

```
import json
import Link_Class
import Music_Database
from pprint import pprint
m = Link_Class.MusicLink()
import webbrowser

search = raw_input("Find this Song: ")
results= m.searchSong(search)
pprint(results)
```

My json file is:

```
{"LinkCollection":

[{"title":"I Will Always Love You" , 
"artist":"Whitney Houston" ,
"link":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JWTaaS7LdU", 
"id":1},

{"title":"Killing Me Softly" , 
"artist":"Roberta Flack" ,
"link":"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LQ2t5e7stVM", 
"id":2}
]}
```

There are more, but for simplicity, I did not write all the data here.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done quite simply with [json.load](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load):

```
with open('your_file.json', 'r') as out:
    data = json.load(out)

# then fetch you data

for song in data['LinkCollection']:
    if song['title'] == search:
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(song['link'])
        break
```

Comment: The video did not come out. Do I need to add more code to activate it?

Comment: Did you try to just print the link to make sure it was found?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to print something from an array. I know how to do it for a list.

Comment: just use `print song['link']` instead of `webbrowser.open_new_tab(song['link'])`

Comment: Nothing popped up. The search is fine but no new code comes up after it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want to open the first result?

```
link = results['LinkCollection'][0]['link']
webbrowser.open_new_tab(link)
```

Comment: Yeah, I do. And I got an error when I tried doing it. I got: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\homare\workspace\Karaoke\main.py", line 30, in <module>
    link = results['LinkCollection'][0]['link']
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str